# Why does it return even, odd, and zero might not have been initialized?

Tags: java

For this code I'm supposed to ask the user to enter a number, say 51706, and tell them how many even digits, odd digits and zeros there are in the number. I'm trying to use the variables even, odd, and zero so I can reference them in the print statement at the bottom, but it's returning that those three variables might not have been initialized. Does anyone know why this is happening and how it might be able to be fixed? note: also I was told by my professor to put even++ instead of even = x for all three variables (even, odd, zero) but I don't understand why that is necessary when x is already being increased.

```
    System.out.print("Please enter a positive number ");
    theNum = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());
    int choice=3, theNum, copy, x, y, counter, even, odd, zero            
    copy = theNum;

    // using a loop display the number of even values and odd values 
    for(x = 0; x>=0; x++);

    if(copy%2 == 0){
        even = x;
    }
    else if(copy%2 == 1){
        odd = x;
    }
    else if(copy == 0){
        zero = x;
    }

    System.out.print(theNum + " has " + even + " evens, " + odd + " odds, " + zero + " zeros")
```

Comment: The compiler isn't good at math.  If you don't have a non-conditional else block, the compiler doesn't know that all paths are covered.

Comment: Also, you need to remove the `;` at the end of the line where you start your for loop.  That immediately terminates the loop, and the stuff that you intended to be the loop body is instead just a sequence of statements inside curly braces that will execute exactly once.  **Edit:** Fixed the formatting of your code, which should hopefully make this more obvious.

Comment: Your integers have a possibility of never getting a value assigned to them according to the compiler due to the conditional blocks around the assignments, and the compiler does not like that. Easiest way to make it happy is to set your integers to something like 0 or -1 before putting the actual value in them.

Comment: As long as we're all here, you might as well know that assigning the integer used for the loop to `even`, `odd`, and `zero` doesn't count them. What I think you mean to do is increment `even`, `odd`, and `zero` on those conditions. After you're done, walk through the code mentally with 120 and a couple of other inputs and satisfy yourself that you have the logic correct.

Comment: In addition, the way you have it now, a 0 digit will be counted as even because it satisfies your first condition so it never tests the third one. Test for 0 first, then for odd and even, to count them separately.